# ui not reflecting proper class upon toggle click

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a toggle button and after wiring it up i noticed that when i click on it - the style doesn't change unless i refresh the page.

Here is my Html:

```
<div (click)="onValueChange(item)">
   <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-toggle-switch" [ngClass]="{'active': item.isActive}">
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="status-on">on</span>
           <span class="status-off">off</span>
        </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

What do i have to do to ensure that upon click the active class is added or removed properly without having to refresh?

Here is my on click function:

```
private onValueChange(item: ItemType) {
        item.isActive = !item.isActive;
        this.save(item);
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] please? As it stands, if I copy your code it works as expected. It seems this is missing some vital context

Comment: may be this.save(item); reset your object to last state